# Multiple X sessions in virtual terminals

Tags: command-line, 13.04, xorg

I installed multiple different window managers over the past day to play around with, but they don't seem to work. I've been launching them from virtual terminals with "startx -- :1 twm" or the like.

1) There's always a shell window onscreen with no prompt. This occurs in every window manager, including Unity (but not the default one on tty7). Commands don't work, except for Ctrl+C, which dumps me to a text-only terminal.

2) If I switch to another virtual terminal, upon my return the window manager will be gone and be replaced by the output of the X server. It stays running, however.

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Try switching to tty1 using Ctrl + Alt + F1, then uninstall most of this windows manager, until you get your desktop back.

Comment: Unity isn't causing an issue. Ctrl+Alt+F7 brings me back to the default window manager without a problem, it's just the running of other window managers from other virtual terminals that's not working.